# What is the Vaishnava interpretation of Sri Rudram?

Tags: vaishnavism

How do Vaishnavas interpret the names of Rudra in connection to Sri Vishnu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Sri Rudram Hymn indicate Lord Shiva or It can be attributed to some other God also?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17294/does-sri-rudram-hymn-indicate-lord-shiva-or-it-can-be-attributed-to-some-other-g)